# Giving EXEC (@Variable) a Column name and Concatenation

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to writing a stored procedure that will check for orphan data before our customers attempt an upgrade, as orphaned records can cause issues. This is what I have thus far;

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE type = 'P' AND name = 'DetectOrphanDataBeforeUpgrade')
DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[DetectOrphanDataBeforeUpgrade]
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[DetectOrphanDataBeforeUpgrade]

@TenantId   INT = NULL

AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @OrphanAuditItems NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @OrphanAuditAnswers NVARCHAR(MAX) 
DECLARE @OrphanAuditQuestion NVARCHAR(MAX)

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/* Throw an error if the TenantId is NULL or Invalid.               */
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
IF @TenantId IS NULL OR @TenantId NOT IN (SELECT Tenants FROM [Application].[dbo].[TenantIdNumber])

BEGIN
    THROW 51000, '@TenantId is invalid because it is NULL or does not exist.', 1;
END


------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/* Checks for Orphan records related to the Audits table                */
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SET @OrphanAuditItems = N'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [Dynamic].['+ CAST (@TenantId AS NVARCHAR) +'].[AuditItems] 
                                                    WHERE FK_Audit NOT IN (SELECT SystemID FROM [Dynamic].['+ CAST (@TenantId AS NVARCHAR) +'].[Audits])'

SET @OrphanAuditAnswers = N'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [Dynamic].['+ CAST (@TenantId AS NVARCHAR) +'].[AuditAnswers] 
                                                        WHERE AuditItemId NOT IN (SELECT SystemID FROM [Dynamic].['+ CAST (@TenantId AS NVARCHAR) +'].[AuditItems])'

SET @OrphanAuditQuestion = N'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [Dynamic].['+ CAST (@TenantId AS NVARCHAR) +'].[AuditQuestion] 
                                                        WHERE AuditId NOT IN (SELECT SystemID FROM [Dynamic].['+ CAST (@TenantId AS NVARCHAR) +'].[Audits])'

EXEC (@OrphanAuditItems)
EXEC(@OrphanAuditAnswers)
EXEC(@OrphanAuditQuestion)

END;
```

At the moment, this script is working, however the output is;

[image: Imagine 1]

I want to return the results on a single line, and have each column with their own name, for example: @OrphanAuditItems result shows as column name: OrphanAuditItems, and so on.

How's the best way to achieve this?

Thanks, 
Tom

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to mix your 3 dynamic SQLs into 1 that returns 3 columns, or keep each dynamic SQL but mix their result at the end. There are 2 possible solutions following:

---

One solution is to use `UNION ALL` and the `PIVOT` to get 1 row with 3 columns, all inside the dynamic SQL.

Change this part:

```
DECLARE @OrphanAuditItems NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @OrphanAuditAnswers NVARCHAR(MAX) 
DECLARE @OrphanAuditQuestion NVARCHAR(MAX)

--.....

SET @OrphanAuditItems = N'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [Dynamic].['+ CAST (@TenantId AS NVARCHAR) +'].[AuditItems] 
                                                    WHERE FK_Audit NOT IN (SELECT SystemID FROM [Dynamic].['+ CAST (@TenantId AS NVARCHAR) +'].[Audits])'

SET @OrphanAuditAnswers = N'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [Dynamic].['+ CAST (@TenantId AS NVARCHAR) +'].[AuditAnswers] 
                                                        WHERE AuditItemId NOT IN (SELECT SystemID FROM [Dynamic].['+ CAST (@TenantId AS NVARCHAR) +'].[AuditItems])'

SET @OrphanAuditQuestion = N'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [Dynamic].['+ CAST (@TenantId AS NVARCHAR) +'].[AuditQuestion] 
                                                        WHERE AuditId NOT IN (SELECT SystemID FROM [Dynamic].['+ CAST (@TenantId AS NVARCHAR) +'].[Audits])'

EXEC (@OrphanAuditItems)
EXEC(@OrphanAuditAnswers)
EXEC(@OrphanAuditQuestion)
```

For this:

```
DECLARE @DynamicSQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'
    ;WITH PrePivot AS
    (
        SELECT 
            Amount = COUNT(*),
            Type = ''OrphanAuditItems''
        FROM 
            [Dynamic].['+ CAST (@TenantId AS NVARCHAR) +'].[AuditItems] 
        WHERE 
            FK_Audit NOT IN (SELECT SystemID FROM [Dynamic].['+ CAST (@TenantId AS NVARCHAR) +'].[Audits]) 

        UNION ALL

        SELECT 
            Amount = COUNT(*),
            Type = ''OrphanAuditAnswers''
        FROM 
            [Dynamic].['+ CAST (@TenantId AS NVARCHAR) +'].[AuditAnswers] 
        WHERE 
            AuditItemId NOT IN (SELECT SystemID FROM [Dynamic].['+ CAST (@TenantId AS NVARCHAR) +'].[AuditItems])

        UNION ALL

        SELECT 
            Amount = COUNT(*),
            Type = ''OrphanAuditQuestion''
        FROM 
            [Dynamic].['+ CAST (@TenantId AS NVARCHAR) +'].[AuditQuestion] 
        WHERE 
            AuditId NOT IN (SELECT SystemID FROM [Dynamic].['+ CAST (@TenantId AS NVARCHAR) +'].[Audits]) 
    )
    SELECT
        P.OrphanAuditItems,
        P.OrphanAuditAnswers,
        P.OrphanAuditQuestion
    FROM
        PrePivot AS T
        PIVOT (
            MAX(T.Amount) FOR T.Type IN ([OrphanAuditItems], [OrphanAuditAnswers], [OrphanAuditQuestion])
        ) AS P '

-- PRINT (@DynamicSQL)
EXEC (@DynamicSQL)
```

Make sure to use the `PRINT` to validate the resulting SQL before executing the `EXEC`.

---

Another solution is to retrieve the values into variables, using `sp_executesql` with `OUTPUT` parameters:

```
-- Items
DECLARE @OrphanAuditItems INT

DECLARE @DynamicSQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'
    SELECT
        @OrphanAuditItems = COUNT(*)
    FROM
        #OrphanResults AS O
        CROSS JOIN [Dynamic].['+ CAST (@TenantId AS NVARCHAR) +'].[AuditItems]
    WHERE 
        FK_Audit NOT IN (SELECT SystemID FROM [Dynamic].['+ CAST (@TenantId AS NVARCHAR) +'].[Audits])'

EXEC sp_executesql 
    @stmt = @DynamicSQL,
    @params = N'@OrphanAuditItems INT OUTPUT',
    @OrphanAuditItems = @OrphanAuditItems OUTPUT


-- Answers
DECLARE @OrphanAuditAnswers INT

SET @DynamicSQL = N'
    SELECT 
        @OrphanAuditAnswers = COUNT(*) 
    FROM 
        [Dynamic].['+ CAST (@TenantId AS NVARCHAR) +'].[AuditAnswers] 
    WHERE 
        AuditItemId NOT IN (SELECT SystemID FROM [Dynamic].['+ CAST (@TenantId AS NVARCHAR) +'].[AuditItems])'

EXEC sp_executesql 
    @stmt = @DynamicSQL,
    @params = N'@OrphanAuditAnswers INT OUTPUT',
    @OrphanAuditAnswers = @OrphanAuditAnswers OUTPUT


-- Questions
DECLARE @OrphanAuditQuestion INT

SET @DynamicSQL = N'
    SELECT 
        @OrphanAuditQuestion = COUNT(*) 
    FROM 
        [Dynamic].['+ CAST (@TenantId AS NVARCHAR) +'].[AuditQuestion] 
    WHERE 
        AuditId NOT IN (SELECT SystemID FROM [Dynamic].['+ CAST (@TenantId AS NVARCHAR) +'].[Audits])'

EXEC sp_executesql 
    @stmt = @DynamicSQL,
    @params = N'@OrphanAuditQuestion INT OUTPUT',
    @OrphanAuditQuestion = @OrphanAuditQuestion OUTPUT

SELECT
    OrphanAuditItems = @OrphanAuditItems,
    OrphanAuditAnswers = @OrphanAuditAnswers,
    OrphanAuditQuestion = @OrphanAuditQuestion
```

I find the latter a bit more flexible and readable than the first.

Comment: Amazing, thank you so much for this EZLo! I have to admit that I have never seen this type of code before as I'm still learning, but this is working perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

One method is with subqueries for each column. The example below also uses `QUOTENAME` to enclose identifiers. Personally, I would name schemas as to conform to [regular identifier naming rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/database-identifiers) rather than using the numeric TenantId as the schema name.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE type = 'P' AND name = 'DetectOrphanDataBeforeUpgrade')
DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[DetectOrphanDataBeforeUpgrade]
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[DetectOrphanDataBeforeUpgrade]

@TenantId   INT = NULL

AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @OrphanAuditData NVARCHAR(MAX)

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/* Throw an error if the TenantId is NULL or Invalid.               */
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
IF @TenantId IS NULL OR @TenantId NOT IN (SELECT Tenants FROM [Application].[dbo].[TenantIdNumber])
BEGIN
    THROW 51000, '@TenantId is invalid because it is NULL or does not exist.', 1;
END


------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/* Checks for Orphan records related to the Audits table                */
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SET @OrphanAuditData = N'SELECT
    (SELECT COUNT(*) 
        FROM [Dynamic].' + QUOTENAME(CAST(@TenantId AS NVARCHAR)) + '.[AuditItems] 
        WHERE FK_Audit NOT IN (SELECT SystemID FROM [Dynamic].' + QUOTENAME(CAST(@TenantId AS NVARCHAR)) + '.[Audits])) AS OrphanAuditItems
'
+ N'    ,(SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM [Dynamic].'+ QUOTENAME(CAST(@TenantId AS NVARCHAR)) + '.[AuditAnswers] 
        WHERE AuditItemId NOT IN (SELECT SystemID FROM [Dynamic].' + QUOTENAME(CAST(@TenantId AS NVARCHAR)) + '.[AuditItems])) AS OrphanAuditAnswers
'
+ N'    ,(SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM [Dynamic].'+ QUOTENAME(CAST(@TenantId AS NVARCHAR)) + '.[AuditQuestion] 
        WHERE AuditId NOT IN (SELECT SystemID FROM [Dynamic].'+ QUOTENAME(CAST(@TenantId AS NVARCHAR)) + '].[Audits])) AS OrphanAuditQuestion;'

EXEC (@OrphanAuditData);

END;
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

I would personally insert all of the data into a holding table in the form of ([COUNT] INT NOT NULL, [TableName] NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL) as below. You can then use PIVOT as below to get the values for each table.

As an aside, please also note the use of the QUOTENAME function - this will ensure your code isn't vulnerable to SQL injection if the table is passed in as a variable (I would look to simply provide a list of table names and have it run through them all dynamically personally - happy to write this out and provide as an answer if you'd like).

```
CREATE TABLE #Datas (ID INT);

INSERT INTO #Datas
(
    ID
)
VALUES
( 1  -- ID - int
    )
    GO

DECLARE @SQL1 NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT COUNT(1), ''TableName1'' FROM ' + QUOTENAME('#Datas') + ';'
DECLARE @SQL2 NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT COUNT(1), ''TableName2'' FROM ' + QUOTENAME('#Datas') + ';'
DECLARE @SQL3 NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT COUNT(1), ''TableName3'' FROM ' + QUOTENAME('#Datas') + ';'

CREATE TABLE #Counts (Cnt INT, Tbl NVARCHAR(MAX));

INSERT INTO #Counts
EXEC (@SQL1);

INSERT INTO #Counts
EXEC (@SQL2);

INSERT INTO #Counts
EXEC (@SQL3);

SELECT * FROM #Counts

PIVOT (SUM(Cnt) FOR Tbl IN ([TableName1],[TableName2],[TableName3])) AS d

DROP TABLE #Datas;
DROP TABLE #Counts
```

[dbfiddle repro](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=8df99ed00abe497d89cf63a6a5b4d63a)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using SQL Server 2012 or later,  you can also just use `WITH RESULT SETS` with your `EXEC`:

```
exec (N'select 1') 
WITH RESULT SETS
(
    (
        ID int
    )
)
```

[image: Result Set]